# Run MsAccess query in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I would like to execute a query stored in MsAcces database in c#. I keep getting an error in "CreateDataReader" the error message:

> "string" does not contain a definition for "CreateDataReader" and
>   was not found an extension method "CreateDataReader" receiver type
>   "string" as the first argument.

Here is the code, could someone tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\uchet_tovarov.mdb");
        String cmd = string.Format("сумма_определ_товара");
        OleDbCommand oleCmd = new OleDbCommand(cmd);

        oleCmd.CommandText = "сумма_определ_товара";
        oleCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        IDataReader dr = cmd.CreateDataReader(oleCmd);

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dr.GetInt32(0).ToString());
        }              
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, `cmd` here is a string:

```
IDataReader dr = cmd.CreateDataReader(oleCmd);
```

Looks like you’re looking for `oleCmd`, your command object:

```
IDataReader dr = oleCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Now i don't det an error, but when i click the button it doesn't do anything. The query works fine in MsAcces, this is the query: SELECT c.kod_tovara, ROUND(AVG(kol*cena),2) AS сумма_даного_товара
FROM realizacia
GROUP BY c.kod_tovara;
Could you help me out?

Answer (score -1):

Look at this line:

```
String cmd = string.Format("сумма_определ_товара");
```

The class name `String` must start with a capital letter in both places. Try first with this one:

```
String cmd = String.Format("сумма_определ_товара");
```